# How can I communicate with Cloudfront and the ec2 node server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

### using stack

`Client:` React, Redux, axios

`Server:` AWS-EC2, Route 53, S3, CloudFront, NodeJS, express

**First,** I bought a domain from route53.(ACM certificate issuance completed)

**Second,** I registered the build file in the bucket as a static website in S3.

**Third,** linked the Route 53 and S3 bucket to CloudFront.

**Fourth,** EC2 set ELB and EIP.

**Fifth,** ec2 contains node.js epxress server.

**Sixth,** CloudFront, Redirect from S3 ([www.domain.link](http://www.domain.link) => domain.link)
was set to

The code of the problematic Client and Server is as follows.

#### Client.js

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { TYPES, MAF } from "./types";
const API_AUTH = "https://www.domain.link/auth";
const API_USER = "https://www.domain.link";
//필수!!
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export function loggedIn(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${API_AUTH}/login`, data).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({
        type: TYPES.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        // payload: res.data.userData,
      });

      dispatch({
        type: MAF.HIDE_MODAL,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function register(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${API_AUTH}/register`, data).then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: TYPES.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    });
  };
}
```

#### server.js

#### `./routes/user.js`

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

const {
  login,
  register,
  logout,
  profile,
} = require("../controller/userController/userController");
const { authorization } = require("../config/JWTConfig");

router.post("/auth/login", login);
router.post("/auth/register", register);
router.get("/auth/logout", authorization, logout);
router.get("/auth/profile", authorization, profile);

module.exports = router;
```

#### `./app.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
// const passportConfig = require("./passport/index");
const passport = require("passport");
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");

require("dotenv").config();
const authRoute = require("./routes/users");
const mainRoute = require("./routes/main");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

const whitelist = [
  "http://localhost:3000",
  "http://*.doamin.link",
  "http://doamin.link",
  "http://doamin.link/*",
];
const corsOption = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTION"],
};

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(cors(corsOption));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(mainRoute);
app.use(authRoute);

let server;

if (fs.existsSync("./cert/key.pem") && fs.existsSync("./cert/cert.pem")) {
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/cert/key.pem", "utf8");
  const certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/cert/cert.pem", "utf8");
  const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

  server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
  server.listen(port, () => console.log("https server Running"));
} else {
  server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`http server Running`);
  });
}

module.exports = server;
```

When I click the Postman or browser login button, this error occurs.

```js
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.domain.link/login' 
from origin 'https://domain.link' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```js
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:84)
```

domain.link or [www.domain.link](http://www.domain.link) or the above error occurs.

#### `Postman`

[image]

How do I get CloudFront + S3 to communicate with EC2?

in your browser or postman

[www.domain.link](http://www.domain.link)
After connecting to domain.link

When you make a login button or post request

I hope it works well.

##### If something is missing, please let me know what is missing. I will add more.

Comment: Did you enable POST in your CloudFront?

Comment: Nope, where do I add that on CloudFront? Origins? Behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

You specify [allowed methods for CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesAllowedHTTPMethods) in your cache behavior. By default only GET and HEAD are allowed:

[image]

Comment: Ah, speaking of this, I chose that one. However, I still get the cors error.

Comment: @spec Your origin is S3 or EC2 instance?

Comment: The domain registered in route53 was linked to s3 with cloudfront.

`domain.link`, `www.domain.link`

ec2 is not registered in origin.

Comment: @spec  POST is not supported for S3 everywhere. Check docs I linked for details.

Comment: @spec How did it go? Still unclear why it may not work for you?